# Copying multiple ranges but get runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to copy multiple ranges and then paste it to word. I have set multiple ranges and joined then with the Union prefix. But everytime i run the code i get error code 1004. The range `mRange` have been dimmed and set and i have tried to change names, specify sheets ect. but it still does not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub ExportToWord()
'Option Explicit

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table
Dim SrcePath As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range, mRange As Range

If Cells(4, 17) = True Then
    'Copies the specified range in excel
    Set sht = Worksheets("Calculations")
    Set StartCell = Range("M3")

    'Refresh UsedRange
    Worksheets("Calculations").UsedRange

    'Find Last Row
    LastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Select Range
    sht.Range("M3:R" & LastRow).Copy

Else
    'copies the specified range
    Set range1 = Range("M3:R5")
    Set range2 = Range("M6:O" & Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set range3 = Range("Q6:R" & Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set mRange = Union(range1, range2, range3)

    mRange.Copy
End If
```

Comment: before the set mRange line do `debug.print rangename.address` for range1/2/3 and tell us what they come out as.

Comment: Runtime error 424 object required.

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't change `rangename` to `range1`/etc?

Comment: When changed, i does not say anything except error 1004 when it reaches mRange.copy.

Comment: press `control+g`, text should have appeared in the `immediate window`

Comment: It comes out with this then:
$M$3:$R$5
$M$5:$O$6
$Q$5:$R$6
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5,$M$5:$O$6,$Q$5:$R$6
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5,$M$5:$O$6,$Q$5:$R$6

Comment: @Sidvidon't use the code from my answer, as it will confuse other users in the future to understand the where the problem occured, and what was the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relying to much on `ActiveSheet`, also you are `Set`ting your `Set sht = Worksheets("Calculations")` inside the `If`, you need to take it out before the first `If`, see code below:

```
' ===== First: set the worksheet object =====
Set sht = Worksheets("Calculations")

With sht
    If .Cells(4, 17) = True Then
        'Copies the specified range in excel
        Set StartCell = .Range("M3")

        'Find Last Row
        LastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'Select Range
        .Range("M3:R" & LastRow).Copy                    
    Else
        'copies the specified range
        Set range1 = .Range("M3:R5")
        Set range2 = .Range("M6:O" & .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set range3 = .Range("Q6:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set mRange = Union(range1, range2, range3)

        mRange.Copy
    End If
End With
```

---

In order to copy multiple `Selections` (different Ranges Areas), you will have to loop through the `Areas` and copy each one of them:

```
 Dim C As Range

 For Each C In mRange.Areas
     C.Copy
     ' do here your Paste section

 Next C
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i still get a error 1004.

Comment: @Sidvi what value do you get if you add `Debug.Print mRange.Address` ?

Comment: I get this:
$M$3:$R$5
$M$5:$O$6
$Q$5:$R$6
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5,$M$5:$O$6,$Q$5:$R$6
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5
$M$3:$R$5,$M$5:$O$6,$Q$5:$R$6

Comment: @Sidvi your result doesn't make any sense, do you have a loop somewhere ?

Comment: I have updated the question to contain the full code from the sub, but there is no loops in the code no.

Comment: @Sidvi it's because your `range1`, `range2` and `range3` are overlapping

Comment: How are they overlapping? its because i need the header that is from M3:R5 minus column O from O5, and data from M6 to R(lastrow) without column O.

Comment: @Sidvi see my comment at the lower part of my answer

Comment: If you look at the code in the questions, i cannot do it that way because it is to be pasted to a word document and saved. that is why i need to copy it all at once.

Comment: @Sidvi in your `Range`s case it can't work, read here why: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214080/xl2000-error-message-that-command-cannot-be-used-on-multiple-selection

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! i just need to hide the column i dont need then.

Answer (score 0):

`1004` happens quite often, when you are not defining the worksheet of the range/cell. In case it is not defined, Excel refers to the `ActiveSheet` as a parent and this is not always what is intended.

Make sure to define every `Row`, `Column`, `Cell` or `Range` with its parent. Like this:

```
Set sht = Worksheets("Calculations")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("M3")

'Find Last Row
LastRow = sht.Range("M" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set range2 = sht.Range("M6:O" & sht.Range("O" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Or you can use `With Worksheets("Calculations")`, it would look better:

```
With Worksheets("Calculations")
    LastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set range2 = .Range("M6:O" & .Range("O" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

---

In your case, you are probably trying to make a `Union()` of ranges that are on different `Worksheets()`. Thus, it gives `1004` error:

E.g. this gives error:

```
set k = Union(Worksheets(1).Range("A1"),Worksheets(2).Range("A2"))
```

This is ok, because the worksheet is the same:

```
set k = Union(Worksheets(1).Range("A1"),Worksheets(1).Range("A2"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that works fine, the problem is the mRange property after the Else statement.

Comment: @Sidvi - try to rewrite your code and it would be just fine. Or write `MsgBox (range1.Parent.Name & range2.Parent.Name , range3.Parent.Name)` before the error and see what happens.

Comment: Given there is no worksheet change in the middle of the unqualified references the suggestion for the union problem you make is unlikely to be correct vityata.

Comment: Using the msgbox i get "CalculationsCalculationsCalculations" so the parant should be ok. Now it says method or data member not found and it marks mRange.